# Creating a Symfony 4 Form without Database

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

I'm new to symfony and want to to create a simple contact form, take the submitted values and send them as an Email. I don't want to save anything in the database.

I followed the documentation on this page: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html

I created a new page/action with the code from the page above:

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/contact", name="page_contact")
     */
    public function contact(Request $request)
    {
        $defaultData = ['message' => 'Type your message here'];
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('message', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('send', SubmitType::class)
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // data is an array with "name", "email", and "message" keys
            $data = $form->getData();
        }

        return $this->render('Shop/contact.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form
        ]);
    }
```

But this gives me an error:

```
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\InvalidArgumentException:
Could not load type "Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TextType": class does not implement "Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface".

  at vendor/symfony/form/FormRegistry.php:89
  at Symfony\Component\Form\FormRegistry->getType('Doctrine\\DBAL\\Types\\TextType')
     (vendor/symfony/form/FormFactory.php:74)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory->createNamedBuilder('name', 'Doctrine\\DBAL\\Types\\TextType', null, array())
     (vendor/symfony/form/FormBuilder.php:97)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->create('name', 'Doctrine\\DBAL\\Types\\TextType', array())
     (vendor/symfony/form/FormBuilder.php:256)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->resolveChildren()
     (vendor/symfony/form/FormBuilder.php:206)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->getForm()
     (src/Controller/ShopController.php:68)
  at App\Controller\ShopController->contact(object(Request))
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:149)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:66)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:190)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (public/index.php:37)
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is there all the `Doctrine` stuff in the Stack Trace?

Comment: Your IDE should have warned you about the namespace issues.

Comment: Im using phpStorm with symfony plugin. But the wrong namespace is valid and `->add('name', TextType::class)` just takes the the wrong class as parameter, I don't use any methods of `TextType`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably imported the wrong type. Instead of:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TextType;
```

you need:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
```

Answer (score 1):

'form' => $form->createView()
instead of 'form' => $form